# constant damage loss in trigger zone, unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

How can i damage my FirstPersonCharacter's health constantly while it's in the trigger zone? It loses its damage only when it enters `onBeginOverlap` on the trigger zone.
Here is my blueprint:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create Timer with your DamageOverTime function and call him every **X** sec, until onEndOverlap occur.

simple example:
[image]

[Here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/HowTo/UseTimers/Blueprints/) you can find much more about timers in BP

Comment: I think this is what he needs , +1

Answer (score 0):

In c++ I would connect it either to the time handle or Tick event which is using delta seconds, but I'm not into blueprints yet so I can give you a small advice to start off with.

You need a loop and check if the character is in the zone or not. The easiest way is to set a bool variable, set it to true when it enters, and keep damaging while the variable is true and stop it when it's set back to false (when he leaves the zone).

Hope it helps a bit.